# How can I find div control of a repeater in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this div inside a repeater.

```
<div class="view" id="View">
```

I want this div control in asp.net c# code. This is my code now:

```
 HtmlGenericControl h3name = null;
 h3name = (HtmlGenericControl)RepeaterView2.Items[count].FindControl("View");
 h3name.Style.Add("width", CHeight.ToString());
```

But I did not get the control. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show the Repeater html code looks like you have not passed the correct name or case in FindControl method

Answer (score 12):

`HtmlGenericControl` defines the methods, properties, and events for all HTML server control elements not represented by a specific .NET Framework class.
So if its a server control you can simply use:

```
HtmlGenericControl sample= e.Item.FindControl("YOURDIVNAME") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

and also add `runet="server"` to your `div`.

Comment: Another version (I think it looks cleaner) could be `HtmlGenericControl sample = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("YOURDIVNAME");`

Comment: @jlg it may throw exception if it is null.

Answer (score 2):

Your `div` must be with `runat = "server"` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

First add a runat server in your div

```
<div class="view" id="View" runat="server">
```

now in item bound event of your repeater find it like

```
HtmlGenericControl sample= e.Item.FindControl("View") as HtmlGenericControl
```